# how to read subfolders of a directory and write to a text file in django view

Tags: python, django, user-interface, django-views

I have to read subfolder names of a directory and write it to text file in a django view

I have already tried the following code but the UI doesnt load with this code.

```
def start(request):
    try:
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    os.chdir("/Volumes/localStorage2/DHLData/DHLs")
    subfolders=os.listdir()
    os.chdir(cwd)
    file = open("/Volumes/localStorage2/DHL/UI/dhl_list.txt", "w")
        for i in subfolders:    
            file.write(i)
        file.close()
```

I have written the whole code of the view

```
def start(request):
    try:
    #cwd=os.getcwd()
    # os.chdir("/Volumes/localStorage2/DHLData/DHLs")
    #subfolders=os.listdir()
    # os.chdir(cwd)
    # file =open("/Volumes/localStorage2/DHL/UI/dhl_list.txt","w")
    # for i in subfolders:  
        # file.write(i)
        # file.write("\n")
    # file.close()
    dhl_list = []    
    if os.path.exists("/Volumes/localStorage2/DHLData/DHLs"):        
        with open("/Volumes/localStorage2/DHL/UI/dhl_list.txt") as dhlListFile:
            for dhl_name in dhlListFile:
                dhl_list.append(dhl_name)    
    return render(request, "i3_flow.html",{"dhl_list":dhl_list})
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())    
    return render(request, "i3_flow.html")
```

Comment: Can you provide more details...what exactly is not working...writing folder names to file or reading the file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, using `glob` and `os` (both in the standard library):
`r_subfolders` contains their relative names, `a_subfolders` their absolute names.

```
import os
import glob

my_path = "/Volumes/localStorage2/DHLData/DHLs"

r_subfolders = []
a_subfolders = []

for filename in glob.glob("%s/*" % my_path):
    if os.path.isdir(filename):
        r_subfolders += [filename[len(my_path)+1:]]
        a_subfolders += [filename]

print(r_subfolders)
print(a_subfolders)
```